# Why this way of copying files isn't working

Tags: c, file-copying

I'm writing a wrapper to help me in my future projects (I finished C book), and want to copy a file without using `fgetc`. Here's my code, it doesn't work:

```
int CopyFile(char* filename, char* dest)
{
  FILE* fp, *fout;
  fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
  //fout = fopen(dest, "wb");
  if(fp == NULL)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  /*while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    fputc(c,fout);
  }*/
  long size = GetFileSize(fp);
  printf("%lu", size);
  char* file = malloc(size);
  fread(file, size, 1, fp);
  //fclose(fp);
  fout = fopen(dest, "wb");
  fwrite(file, size, 1, fout);
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fout);
  return 0;

}
```

I even open the files with a hexeditor and they aren't similar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *How* do the files differ? In size? The contents? Are you sure the size returned by `GetFileSize` is correct? Have you checked that the [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) or [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) calls fail? Or doesn't read/write all you requested? What does `GetFileSize` do?

Comment: see [GetFileSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That doesn't seem to be the same function the OP uses in the program shown.

Comment: Just a note not directly related to the question, but I find difficult to read code where variable name is ambiguous. For example "file" can as well represent a file pointer, "contents" or "fileContents" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I also do not judge. but Perhaps `GetFileSize(fp);` is wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It seems that the OPs program builds an runs, and I doubt neither of that would work if the OP intended to use the WINAPI function.

Comment: Files size are equal, what differ is the content. Btw here is the GetFileSize:http://pastebin.com/AwNQ1PyK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `GetFileSize` function, where you move the file-pointer to the end, but you never [rewind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) to the beginning again.

That means your `fread` function call will not actually read anything, as the pointer already is at the end of the file. So what's written is the contents of the allocated memory, which is indeterminate (and will be seemingly random).

If you checked what `fread` returned, you would have seen this immediately.

Let this be a lesson on always checking the return values of functions which can fail in one way or the other.

Comment: Man you're the best ty <3 
When i coded the function i was thinking that the file rewinded with the return(so stupid).